# Вывод символа из слова в консоли

Tags: java, консоль

Помогите написать программу ,которая будет запускаться из терминала или консоли.
Она должна брать данные из строки запуска программы:

> 1 аргумент - слово
>
> 2 аргумент - целое число n

с проверкой корректности введенных данных (не используя регулярные выражения)

Итогом обработки должен быть вывод в консоль n-го символа из введенного слова:

```
"В слове <слово> <n>-й символ <символ>"
```

То есть, допустим в консоли вводим два аргумента:

> Young 4

И получаем:

> В слове Young 4 символ n

---

matches 0 - 9 надо заменить,т.к. - это регулярное выражение.
Нужно упростить программу

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String text = args[0];

        if (!text.matches("[0-9]+")) {

            int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

            if (text.length() < n) {
                System.out.println("V SLOVE " + text + " " + text.length() + " BUKV!");
            } else {
                getPositionText(text, n);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("V SLOVE " + text + " EST CIFRA");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PROPISHITE CIFRY");
    }

}

private static void getPositionText(String text, int count) {
    if (count != 0) {
        count = count - 1;
    }
    System.out.println("VCE OK " + text + " " + count + " SIMVOL : " + text.charAt(count));
}
```

}

Comment: думаю тебе лучше сейчас попробывать самому что-то написать, а если что-то не получится задать вопрос

Comment: @UlaLa Попробовал

Answer (score 4):

Код:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Аргументов может быть только 2
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Run with two arguments!");
            return;
        }
        
        String word = args[0];
        String posStr = args[1];
        
        int pos;
        
        // Проверка на корректное число
        try {
            pos = Integer.parseInt(posStr);
        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number: " + posStr);
            return;
        }

        char symbol = word.charAt(pos - 1);
        
        String text = String.format("В слове %s %s-й символ %s", word, posStr, symbol);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```